# Avoiding no such column error in sqlalchemy when querying all columns except the manually added one

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got an existing sqlite3 table which has been created without a primary key. I'm using automap to automatically generate the class. In order to get automap to work, as it expects a primary key, I've manually added a primary key column:

```
    appuser = db.Table(
        'AppUser',
         metadata,
         db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True),
         extend_existing=True,
         autoload=True,
         autoload_with=engine
    )
```

Now I get an error complaining about missing id any time I try to query all columns. I'd rather not have to specify the columns every time the table is queried, this is done later when the data is presented.

Is there a way to get around this without explicitly mentioning all columns? I tried the deferred and defer options to no success.

Adding deferred to column like so: `deferred(db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True))` just resulted in error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: 'SchemaItem' object, such as a 'Column' or a 'Constraint' expected, got <ColumnProperty at 0x7fa96bc4c6d0; no key>

And adding defer to the query options also resulted in the same missing id error:

```
        userRecords = self.session.query(appuser).all()
        userRecords.options(defer('id'))
        for row in userRecords:
            print(row)
```

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: appuser.id

The error occurs in the for line, so I can't even print out individual attributes like so: `print(row.app, row.username)`

Comment: Your question is misleading. What you want is to force automap to use a table that was created with no primary key. IMHO either you can add a primary key **in the database**, or automap will not be able to process that table. IMHO you should delete this question and ask a new one more explicit on your real requirements.

Comment: Automap documentation mentions this method for constructing table objects. I just want to know how to iterate over the table object which isn't described in the documentation, so I don't see why my question is invalid.

Comment: Automap documentation also says that *valid* tables must have a primary key... I really think that the problem is there.